# How to Open File Dialog box on SPA (browser side) with custom file list (of remote, server directory)

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I have a MVC project with a view. Have a directory on server with files, and have to show good looking Open File dialog box with this directory and files in it (not a user's local directory). I got a list of files, and path, and send as variables (string and array of strings) into my view, so now I can show directory listing on my page. But I'd like to use some standard looking dialog box for choosing file instead of writing my own window with radio buttons and text boxes.
Is there any way to fill Open file dialog box with my list of files With Javascript?

Comment: Please, include the code of what you have tried on your question, besides being a good practice, it helps other users to answer your problem, avoid asking such low-effort questions, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the buttons, you can take a look at bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/

There you can use predefined buttons, lists etc. But specifically for downloading files there is no SPECIAL button of any kind.

Regarding the JS part, you can use something like:

```
<a id="download_link" download=filename.txt" href=”” onclick="getFile('someinputtxt')"><font size="5">Download Txt File</font></a>

<script> 
    function getFile(input)
    { 
    var text =  input;
    var data = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

document.getElementById('download_link').href = url;
} 
</script>
```

There I create a text file with some input. But basically you can use a button/list that is already in bootstrap for example and just add the file using 'download':

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for reply. and sorry for poor explanations.

I can make my own window with files listed and options to choose one, and with button Open. But I'd like to find a way to use common Open File dialog box with my custom list of files. 
I've got remote files' list, sent it into my MVC controller, sent it into my MVC view as an List/array, and now I'm looking for a way to fill Open File dialog box with this list, or find very similar control/dialog box.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if I understood the question correctly.  But if you want to create the list dynamically I would suggest you to have a look at JQUERY or EJS: https://ejs.co/. With EJS you can write code inside your HTML for example, you make a loop where you put a new item in your dialog box for each array entry. For example it would look like: "<% 
for (var i = result.comments.length - 1; 0 <=  i; i--) { %>
    <br>
        <div > ...". If it helps please vote up my answers.

Comment: Thank you. I think I can not explain the question. Maybe I will try again later. Sorry for disturbing.

Comment: You are not disturbing. You can make a picture maybe where you show what you want to get, or even better some example code. That would help a lot in understanding the issue.